# All the accordion rows opening at once, how to fix?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, umbraco

This page makes use of an accordion containing a rich-text element within.  JS is used to toggle an active class which changes the max-height value on it, revealing the abstract content within.

I had an issue where hyperlinks wouldn't work within because the max-height value was interfering; causing the accordion to open/close again rather than being able to target the text (tried using z-index but it didn't seem to do the trick).

I went back into the JS and CSS file in order to target the heading of the accordion as a separate class.  This solved the issue with the hyperlinks, but now when I click on one of the accordions, all of them open at once which hasn't happened before.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cp0PA.png)

**The Markup**

```
<div class="accordion-row">
@foreach ( var item in Model.Items ) {
    <div class="teaser">
    <div class="teaser-title">
        @item.GetValue( "title" )
  </div>
        <div class="abstract">
            @Html.Raw(item.GetValue( "content" ))
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**Script**

```
var pullTeaser = $('.teaser-title');
  menuTeaser = $('.abstract');

$(pullTeaser).on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      menuTeaser.toggleClass('slide');
      $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var pullTeaser = $('.teaser-title');
  menuTeaser = $('.abstract');

$(pullTeaser).on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent().find(menuTeaser).toggleClass('slide');
      $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
  });
```